# How to pick one response from multiple responses using aggregator in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

suppose a user hitting a rest service url and i want to send the request to multiple rest services and using some rule in aggregator i want to pick best response which matching the rule and send that  response back to user?

use case 
browser url - a rest request
multicast - to send to multiple services
aggregator - pick the best response
send back best response to browser url.

But im getting only latest multicast response not best one from aggregator. any help?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Scatter-Gather EIP example [here](http://camel.apache.org/scatter-gather.html)